# How to add distinct value in database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
IEnumerable<WebsiteWebPage> data = GetWebPages();

foreach (var value in data)
{
    if (value.WebPage.Contains(".htm"))
    {
        WebsiteWebPage pagesinfo = new WebsiteWebPage();
        pagesinfo.WebPage = value.WebPage;
        pagesinfo.WebsiteId = websiteid;

        db.WebsiteWebPages.Add(pagesinfo);
    }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

I want to add only distinct values to database in above code. Kindly help me how to do it as I am not able to find any solution.

Comment: What do you mean distinct values? What is unique value here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need them to be unique by WebPage and WebSiteId

```cs
IEnumerable<WebsiteWebPage> data = GetWebPages();
foreach (var value in data)
{
    if (value.WebPage.Contains(".htm"))
    {
        WebsiteWebPage pagesinfo = new WebsiteWebPage();
        if (db.WebsiteWebPages.All(c=>c.WebPage != value.WebPage|| c.WebsiteId != websiteid))
        {
            pagesinfo.WebPage = value.WebPage;
            pagesinfo.WebsiteId = websiteid;
            db.WebsiteWebPages.Add(pagesinfo);
        }
     }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

## UPDATE

To optimize this (given that your table contains much more data than your current list), override your `equals` in `WebsiteWebPage` class to define your uniqueness criteria then:

```cs
var myWebsiteWebPages = data.select(x=> new WebsiteWebPage { WebPage = x.WebPage, WebsiteId = websiteid}).Distinct();
var duplicates = db.WebsiteWebPages.Where(x=> myWebsiteWebPage.Contains(x));
db.WebsiteWebPages.AddRange(myWebsiteWebPages.Where(x=> !duplicates.Contains(x)));
```

this is a one database query to retrieve ONLY duplicates and then removing them from the list

Comment: I guess `db.WebsiteWebPages.All(..)` will issue a `SELECT` request for each and every `value` in `data`?

Comment: Yes, it will. And if there is 10 000 items in the list - this will be 10 000 useless SQL queries.

Comment: @vasily.sib Agree... this isn't how I would write this, but this is how I'd answer someone who asks me what's wrong with his code... your solution could very well be MUCH worse than mine with a huge table compared to the number of items

Comment: LINQ-to-Entities can't handle `.Where(x=> myWebsiteWebPage.Contains(x))`, more then that, you need to override not only `.Equals()`, but also `.GetHashCode()` to use parameters-less version of `.Distinct()`

Comment: @vasily.sib EF 4+ supports `Contains()` queries

Comment: try it, and you will get `Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context` exception

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by *"distinct values"* you mean *"distinct `value.WebPage` values"*:

```
// get existing values (if you ever need this)
var existingWebPages = db.WebsiteWebPages.Select(v => v.WebPage);
// get your pages
var webPages = GetWebPages().Where(v => v.WebPage.Contains(".htm"));

// get distinct WebPage values except existing ones
var distinctWebPages = webPages.Select(v => v.WebPage).Distinct().Except(existingWebPages);
// create WebsiteWebPage objects
var websiteWebPages = distinctWebPages.Select(v =>
    new WebsiteWebPage { WebPage = v, WebsiteId = websiteid});

// save all at once
db.WebsiteWebPages.AddRange(websiteWebPages);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: that guarantees you're inserting distinct values, but doesn't guarantee that these values doesn't already exist in the db, and thus that you're inserting a distinct duplicate

Comment: @jalsh, now its guarantees that these values doesn't already exist in the db

Comment: So, if this is inserting 5 items in a ~1 billion record table, you'd be loading a few GBs in memory and iterate over these?

Comment: So, if this is inserting ~1 billion items in a 5 record table, you'd be loading a few GBs from memory to DB and let it iterate over these? (you will also iterate over it on your side to serialize it for sending)

Comment: exactly my point, you cannot tell what is the optimal solution for his problem, you just give him a working solution and when he asks about the performance and gives his info then you’d do it

Answer (score 0):

```
   IEnumerable<WebsiteWebPage> data = GetWebPages();

                        foreach (var value in data)
                        {
                            if (value.WebPage.Contains(".htm"))
                            {
                                var a = db.WebsiteWebPages.Where(i => i.WebPage == value.WebPage.ToString()).ToList();
                                if (a.Count == 0)
                                {
                                    WebsiteWebPage pagesinfo = new WebsiteWebPage();
                                    pagesinfo.WebPage = value.WebPage;
                                    pagesinfo.WebsiteId = websiteid;
                                    db.WebsiteWebPages.Add(pagesinfo);
                                    db.SaveChanges();
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

This is the code that I used to add distinct data.I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code,

```
IEnumerable<WebsiteWebPage> data = GetWebPages();

var templist = new List<WebsiteWebPage>();
foreach (var value in data)
{
    if (value.WebPage.Contains(".htm"))
    {
        WebsiteWebPage pagesinfo = new WebsiteWebPage();
        pagesinfo.WebPage = value.WebPage;
        pagesinfo.WebsiteId = websiteid;

        templist.Add(pagesinfo);
    }
}
var distinctList = templist.GroupBy(x => x.WebsiteId).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
db.WebsiteWebPages.AddRange(distinctList);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or you can use **MoreLINQ** [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) to filter distinct the list by parameter like,

```
var res = tempList.Distinct(x=>x.WebsiteId).ToList();
db.WebsiteWebPages.AddRange(res);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `WebsiteWebPage` is an object, so `templist.Distinct()` will check by references and not by `WebPage` value, so all items in `templist` will remain

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the code sample Furkan Öztürk supplied, Make sure your DB has a constraint so that you cannot enter duplicate values in the column. Belt and braces approach.